# c# check if charAt is empty

Tags: c#

In my program, the user has to input 5 numbers (with different number of digits).

```
int[] num = new int[5];
        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter number" + (x + 1) + ": ");
            num[x] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

Getting the max length:

```
int maxLength = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            string c = num[x].ToString();
            int l = c.Length;
            if (l > maxLength)
                maxLength = l;
        }
```

Now, I want to check if the other numbers have the same length of digits or not. And if not, I'll add 0 (or 0's depending on the length) as the last digit/s of that number.
How do I check if the charAt (or in c# the num[x]) of that number is null or empty?

I tried:

```
if(c[maxLength] == ' ')
```

but I'm getting a System.IndexOutOfRangeException error

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException is self explanatory. `Index is Out of Range` comes when trying to access index which does not exist.

Comment: There isn't any number for which `num[x].ToString()` might include a space. You say you want to check its length, so why are you trying to check its contents at all? You already know how to obtain its length.

Answer (score 0):

change x<5 in second for loop

```
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `num[x]` can never be `null`. It would be either an `int` or your program will crash due to error in the conversion of the input.

```
num[x] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Specifically, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Return Value Type: System.Int32 A 32-bit signed integer that is
>   equivalent to the number in value, or 0 (zero) if value is null.

Regarding the excpected exceptions:

- **Format Exception** (value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).)
- **OverflowException** (value represents a number that is less than Int32.MinValue or greater than Int32.MaxValue.)

**Note**: Furthermore, you should change the upper bound of your second loop. As we can see from you first loop the `num.length` would be 5 and your upper bound (not inclusive) of your second loop is 10 ! You could replace 10 with `num.legnth`, in order if you change later the 5 to not have to change again the upper bound of your second loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can count digits of a number by dividing the number with the base number untill you get zero.

```
int number = 250;
int basenumber = 10;
int digitcount = 0;

for (int temp = number; temp > 0; temp /= basenumber)
    digitcount++;
```

digitcount would be 3 in that case.

Answer (score 0):

First thing in your code you have created int array with length of 5 and trying to get value for 10 element in your loop-

```
<!-- language: c# -->
int[] num = new int[5];
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
```

So that's why you are getting this exception.

Now come to second question- if value will be null then 
so in that case you will get zero if value is not assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
foreach (int number in num)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number * Math.Pow(10, maxLenght - (number != 1 ? Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(number)) : 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can right pad a set of numbers to the length of the longest number:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 10;
            Random r = new Random();
            int[] a = new int[n];

            // Generate some random numbers of different lengths
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                a[i] = r.Next(Convert.ToInt32(new String('9', r.Next(1, 6))));

            // Get length of longest number
            int maxLength = a.Max(x => x.ToString().Length);

            // Create array to store padded numbers
            string[] l = new string[n];

            // Get right zero padded numbers
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                l[i] = a[i].ToString().PadRight(maxLength, '0');

            // Print numbers
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                Console.WriteLine(l[i]);

            // Wait for key-press
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go like follows

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int maxDigits;
        string[] codes = EnterNumber(5, out maxDigits); '<--| '5' is the number of numbers you want the user to input
        codes = UnifyDigits(codes, maxDigits);
    }

    static string[] EnterNumber(int entriesNumber, out int maxDigits)
    {
        string[] entries = new string[entriesNumber];
        int number;
        int maxL=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < entriesNumber; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter a number");
            } while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number) );
            entries[i] = number.ToString();
            maxL = Math.Max(entries[i].Length, maxL);
        }
        maxDigits =maxL;
        return entries;
    }


    static string[] UnifyDigits(string[]entries, int maxDigits)
    {
        string[] unifiedEntries = entries;
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
        {
            if (entries[i].Length<maxDigits)
                entries[i] = entries[i] + new String('0', maxDigits - entries[i].Length);
        }
        return unifiedEntries;
    }
```

Comment: @asdfdsfa did you get through it?